# Initialize and pass map as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I am trying to call the GoogleTest `ASSERT_EQ` macro as follows:

```
ASSERT_EQ(map<string, string> {
  {"a", "x"}, {"b", "y"}
}, some_other_map);
```

But I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax (if it's even possible).

Ideas?

Comment: It works for me. Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/vFRs7Z)

Comment: You're missing the return type from the function declaration, and you'll need C++11 support to brace-initialise a temporary map, but apart from that it works for me: http://ideone.com/Xcdv6w

Comment: You are missing the return type or it's a constructor? It work on GCC 4.9.0 with C++11 with the return type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour mistyped the function definition.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: So does it work when you fix that, and make sure you have C++11 support? If not, and you can't figure out what's still wrong, please let us know the exact error message.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta which compiler are you using?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I just realized it's not a function call, it's a macro. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you've clarified that it's a macro, not a function, the problem is that the preprocessor is an ugly wart on the side of the language, with its own syntax that's not always compatible with the language it's mangling.

Specifically, it doesn't recognise `<` and `>` as brackets, so it thinks there are three comma-separated arguments, not two:

```
map<string
string> {...}
some_other_map
```

You can fix this by putting parentheses around the first expression:

```
ASSERT_EQ((map<string, string> {
    {"a", "x"}, {"b", "y"}
}), some_other_map);
```

In general, try to avoid doing anything complicated with macros. It's usually a route to pain.

Comment: Thanks, at first I didn't realize it was gonna make a difference for macros then a light bulb went off.